# Urban Airship callbackArguments:withOptions: delegate issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, urbanairship.com

I have upgraded Urban Airship SDk 1.4.0 to 3.0.2 . Now I have changed all the methods as
given in their not so handy documentation.

I want to handle rich push, for that I need to handle

```
callbackArguments:withOptions: delegate
```

But its not getting called. Any ideas, how and where to implement this delegate.
Anyone faced this before?

Thanks.

Comment: resolved this issue. If someone seeking solution here it is. I implemented same delegate in UAInboxViewController class under Airship > UI .

Comment: Can you  share the code how to handle that?